# WPF Custom Control inside ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have a custom control, which looks broadly like this:

```
public class MyTextBlockTest : Control
{
    static MyTextBlockTest()
    {
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string),
         typeof(MyTextBlockTest), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(""));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        FontFamily font = new FontFamily("Times New Roman");
        Typeface typeface = new Typeface(font, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal);
        FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(Text,
                                             System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                             System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                                             typeface,
                                             15.0,
                                             Brushes.Black);

        var point = this.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        drawingContext.DrawText(ft, point);            
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use this control inside an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BigList, ElementName=MainWindowView}" Margin="0,-1,0,1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>-->
                <controls:MyTextBlockTest Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If I enable the `TextBlock` that's commented out, the list displays fine; however, with my custom control, WPF isn't placing the text in the right place; more specifically, it seems to be simply printing all elements on top of each other.

The `this.PointToScreen` call was my initial idea to give it a prompt, but I'm unsure (even if this worked, which it doesn't) whether this would react favourably with the ScrollViewer.

I realise I could simply base this control on the TextBlock control, but I specifically want to base it off a lower level control as a performance experiment.  Please could someone point me toward a method to place the Custom Control on the screen correctly?

Comment: Why do you use PointToScreen? What would happen if just draw at (0,0)?

Comment: Tried that initially, it just puts it in the top corner

Comment: Top corner of control or ItemsControl?

Comment: Please note that TextBlock is more "low level" than Control, because it derives directly from FrameworkElement. The PointToScreen thing doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Top corner of the screen.

Comment: I realise pointtoscreen doesn't make sense, I was trying to illustrate the problem (evidently I didn't succeed).

Comment: Your problem is that your control has an empty size, especially zero height. All items are hence drawn on top of each other.

Comment: @Clemens - according to this: http://www.codemag.com/article/100023 both TextBlock and Control derive from FrameworkElement

Comment: That's why your custom TextBlock could also derive from FrameworkElement, instead of Control. Besides that, you don't need all the content and template stuff in Control.

Comment: Yes - once I got it working, I moved it to FrameworkElement, and it shaved some more time off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your minimal custom TextBlock should at least also override the `MeasureOverride` method to return its size. Otherwise the control has zero width and height, and all items in the ItemsControl are drawn on top of each other.

The `Text` property should therefore be registered with the `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure` flag.

```
public class MyTextBlock : FrameworkElement
{
    private FormattedText formattedText;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyTextBlock),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                string.Empty,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure,
                (o, e) => ((MyTextBlock)o).TextPropertyChanged((string)e.NewValue)));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    private void TextPropertyChanged(string text)
    {
        var typeface = new Typeface(
            new FontFamily("Times New Roman"),
            FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal);

        formattedText = new FormattedText(
            text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, 15, Brushes.Black);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        return formattedText != null
            ? new Size(formattedText.Width, formattedText.Height)
            : new Size();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        if (formattedText != null)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawText(formattedText, new Point());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This actually helped me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61962992/wpf-onrender-column-content-overlaps-in-datagrid/61969778#61969778 Problem